# Nonisomorphic groups of order 12.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to find 4 groups of order 12, none of which are isomorphic to each other.  Should I be trying external direct products?

So far I have $A_4, \mathbb Z_{12},\,$ and $\,\mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2.\,$ How do I show all of these are non-isomorphic to each other? And how do I find a fourth?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groups you've found so far:

$$ A_4, \;\mathbb Z_{12}, \mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2$$ are, indeed, **non-isomorphic.** Why?

- By the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian groups, we
  know $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $\mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2 \cong
     \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6$ are abelian and further, that $\mathbb
     Z_{12}\cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_4$ and is cyclic, and not isomorphic to the abelian group $\mathbb
     Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_6$.
  $\mathbb Z_{12} = \mathbb Z_{2\times 6} \not\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6$ because $\gcd(2, 6) = 2\neq 1$. Indeed, $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is cyclic, but $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6$ is not.
- Neither of these two non-isomorphic abelian groups is isomorphic to
  $A_4$, since $A_4$ is not abelian.

Finally, for a *fourth group of order $12$* which is not isomporphic to any of the above three groups, we have $\;\mathbb Z_2\times S_3$. This group is not abelian, and so not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{12},$ nor to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6$. All that's left for you to justify is the fact that $A_4\not\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb S_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, external direct product is need. You can get $A_4$ and $Z_2\times S_3$ are not isomorphic. 
And you can get all groups in abelian case easily.

Comment: if i have two groups G and H, is GxH isomorphic to HxG in general?

Comment: Yes, the two groups are isomrphic.

Comment: so groups that i came up with are Z12, A4, Z6xZ2. i cant think of a fourth one? I don't understand your example

Comment: $S_3$ is a non-abelian group of order 6. So $Z_2 \times S_3$ is of order 12, non-abelian.

Comment: but A4 is also not abelian

Comment: Note $Z_2$ is in the center of $Z_2 \times S_3$. But the center of $A_4$ is trivial. So they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the external direct product for this problem.

There are actually five non-isomorphic groups of order $12$, but you need to find four.  Here are few catches to determine the specific groups:

- Apply the [fundamental theorem of finitely-generated abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).  Be careful of which groups are isomorphic.
- Try to find other groups by constructing homomorphism and applying stabilizer theorem.

> Check the [SPOILERS](https://people.math.osu.edu/all.3/algebra/group%20theory/group3.pdf) for the problem you are stuck in.